# Why is the DataTrigger to set the header of a DataGridColunm not working?

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I am trying to set the header of the `DataGrid` columns according to a value of a property in my view model. I am using this code:

```
<DataGridTextColumn.Header>
    <TextBlock>
        <TextBlock.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                <Setter Property="Text" Value="My Default Header"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=ucPrincipal, Path=DataContext.MyPrperty.ID}" Value="3" >
                        <Setter Property="Text" Value="Header 2"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DataContext.MyProperty.ID, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:myUcViewType}}}" Value="4" >
                        <Setter Property="Text" Value="Header 3"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBlock.Style>
    </TextBlock>
</DataGridTextColumn.Header>
```

But the header is always set to the default value. The values of `ID` are set to 3 and 4 correctly.

I am trying to use two different ways to get the value of the `ID` which is the source property that is used by the `DataTrigger` to set the header text.

Thanks.

Comment: The second binding using an `AncestorType` should work provided that `myUcViewType` is a visual ancestor of the `DataGrid` and its `DataContext` has a public `MyProperty.ID` property. What's the `DataContext` of the `DataGrid`? Please post the code for the properties.

Comment: The only reason why this can't work is that the binding path is wrong or the source is not initialized. The first binding has a typo: "MyPrperty" instead of "MyPr**o**perty" (in case the snippet is a copy of the original code). Validate the binding paths. Read the output window to know binding errors.